# Converting text to table, separator as #

Tags: r, text-files, separator

I am struggling to convert my text file to table in R. Problem is columns are separated by "#" but when I use `read.table()` function with `sep="#"` it still doesn't look like a normal table and returns tons of errors.

How I can solve this?

Text file looks like this:

```
Hotel Van Walsum#121800#3#4.2#70#0.7 miles to City centre?#
Bilderberg Parkhotel Rotterdam#124547#4#3.7#83#0.5 miles to City centre?#
NH Atlanta Rotterdam#208643#4#3.9#55#0.3 miles to City centre?#
Nhow Rotterdam#439534#4#4.3#83#1.3 miles to City centre?#
The Manhattan Hotel Rotterdam#173187#5#4.5#101#0.1 miles to City centre?#
Mainport#427255#5#4.7#112#0.8 miles to City centre?#
easyHotel Rotterdam City Centre#438095#2#3.8#49#0.5 miles to City centre?#
ss Rotterdam Hotel & Restaurants#277518#4#4.3#84#1.8 miles to City centre?#
H2otel#276462#3#4.1#67#0.7 miles to City centre?#
Van der Valk Hotel Rotterdam-Blijdorp#272914#4#4.1#71#1.4 miles to City centre?#
NH Capelle#139024#4#4.1#55#4.5 miles to City centre?#
The Student Hotel Rotterdam#434163#3#4.2#62#1.3 miles to City centre?#
Novotel Rotterdam Brainpark#124868#4#4.4#69#2.4 miles to City centre?#
Hotel Van Walsum#121800#3#4.2#70#0.7 miles to City centre?#
Hampshire Hotel - Savoy Rotterdam#115253#4#3.7#65#0.8 miles to City centre?#
Delta Hotel Rotterdam#179050#4#4.2#80#5.8 miles to City centre?#
Novotel Rotterdam Schiedam#144828#4#4.3#69#4.2 miles to City centre?#
Hotel Rotterdam#209923#4#3.7#74#0.4 miles to City centre?#
```

Comment: Is it because the # mark is a comment out in R? When I tried this quickly, reading in 'Hello#my#name#is#brian', it would only read in 'hello', no matter what character I used as the separator. Would it be easier to re-write the table

Answer (score 5):

We will need to specify the field separator and comment character in `read.table`:

```
read.table("myFile.txt", sep = "#", comment.char = "")
```

Answer (score 5):

You can load it by using a different `comment.char`, one that won't be in your file like #

This works:

```
df <- read.table(text='Hotel Van Walsum#121800#3#4.2#70#0.7 miles to City centre?#
Bilderberg Parkhotel Rotterdam#124547#4#3.7#83#0.5 miles to City centre?#
NH Atlanta Rotterdam#208643#4#3.9#55#0.3 miles to City centre?#
Nhow Rotterdam#439534#4#4.3#83#1.3 miles to City centre?#
The Manhattan Hotel Rotterdam#173187#5#4.5#101#0.1 miles to City centre?#
Mainport#427255#5#4.7#112#0.8 miles to City centre?#
easyHotel Rotterdam City Centre#438095#2#3.8#49#0.5 miles to City centre?#
ss Rotterdam Hotel & Restaurants#277518#4#4.3#84#1.8 miles to City centre?#
H2otel#276462#3#4.1#67#0.7 miles to City centre?#
Van der Valk Hotel Rotterdam-Blijdorp#272914#4#4.1#71#1.4 miles to City centre?#
NH Capelle#139024#4#4.1#55#4.5 miles to City centre?#
The Student Hotel Rotterdam#434163#3#4.2#62#1.3 miles to City centre?#
Novotel Rotterdam Brainpark#124868#4#4.4#69#2.4 miles to City centre?#
Hotel Van Walsum#121800#3#4.2#70#0.7 miles to City centre?#
Hampshire Hotel - Savoy Rotterdam#115253#4#3.7#65#0.8 miles to City centre?#
Delta Hotel Rotterdam#179050#4#4.2#80#5.8 miles to City centre?#
Novotel Rotterdam Schiedam#144828#4#4.3#69#4.2 miles to City centre?#
Hotel Rotterdam#209923#4#3.7#74#0.4 miles to City centre?#', sep='#', comment.char='*')
```

Output:

```
 df
                                      V1     V2 V3  V4  V5                        V6 V7
1                       Hotel Van Walsum 121800  3 4.2  70 0.7 miles to City centre? NA
2         Bilderberg Parkhotel Rotterdam 124547  4 3.7  83 0.5 miles to City centre? NA
3                   NH Atlanta Rotterdam 208643  4 3.9  55 0.3 miles to City centre? NA
4                         Nhow Rotterdam 439534  4 4.3  83 1.3 miles to City centre? NA
5          The Manhattan Hotel Rotterdam 173187  5 4.5 101 0.1 miles to City centre? NA
6                               Mainport 427255  5 4.7 112 0.8 miles to City centre? NA
7        easyHotel Rotterdam City Centre 438095  2 3.8  49 0.5 miles to City centre? NA
8       ss Rotterdam Hotel & Restaurants 277518  4 4.3  84 1.8 miles to City centre? NA
9                                 H2otel 276462  3 4.1  67 0.7 miles to City centre? NA
10 Van der Valk Hotel Rotterdam-Blijdorp 272914  4 4.1  71 1.4 miles to City centre? NA
11                            NH Capelle 139024  4 4.1  55 4.5 miles to City centre? NA
12           The Student Hotel Rotterdam 434163  3 4.2  62 1.3 miles to City centre? NA
13           Novotel Rotterdam Brainpark 124868  4 4.4  69 2.4 miles to City centre? NA
14                      Hotel Van Walsum 121800  3 4.2  70 0.7 miles to City centre? NA
15     Hampshire Hotel - Savoy Rotterdam 115253  4 3.7  65 0.8 miles to City centre? NA
16                 Delta Hotel Rotterdam 179050  4 4.2  80 5.8 miles to City centre? NA
17            Novotel Rotterdam Schiedam 144828  4 4.3  69 4.2 miles to City centre? NA
18                       Hotel Rotterdam 209923  4 3.7  74 0.4 miles to City centre? NA
```

Answer (score 3):

`read.table`,`read.csv`,`read.delim` they all are used to read files and convert into data frame with some subtle variations with respect to each other.

```
read.table(file, header = FALSE, sep = "", quote = "\"'",
           dec = ".", numerals = c("allow.loss", "warn.loss", "no.loss"),
           row.names, col.names, as.is = !stringsAsFactors,
           na.strings = "NA", colClasses = NA, nrows = -1,
           skip = 0, check.names = TRUE, fill = !blank.lines.skip,
           strip.white = FALSE, blank.lines.skip = TRUE,
           comment.char = "#",
           allowEscapes = FALSE, flush = FALSE,
           stringsAsFactors = default.stringsAsFactors(),
           fileEncoding = "", encoding = "unknown", text, skipNul = FALSE)
```

`read.table` has default `comment.char="#"` which means in your text there can be comments denoted by `#`. To read csv files or delimited files by any character use `read.csv` or `read.delim` where there is no default `comment.char` just specify your `sep` character.

Default `read.csv` is

```
read.csv(file, header = TRUE, sep = "#", quote = "\"",
         dec = ".", fill = TRUE, comment.char = "", ...)
```

You can use

```
read.csv(file, sep="#",header=F)
```